# Use [Property] in my managed code signature? Basic MSI

Tags: installshield, managed-code, basic-msi

I cant seem to figure out how to use my [MyProperty] property inside of the custom method signature. I have tried [MyProperty], "[MyProperty]", "MyProperty". ALl i am left with is the actual string being passed and NOT the value of the property. I have tried immediate execution and differed execution in various areas of the sequence but i have found no solution.

I have also tried the "CustomActionData" method from [here](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-201283.html) with no success. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, my post is [here](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?219287-Use-Property-to-set-Shortcut-Folder-Name&p=508523#post508523) with the explanation

Comment: Usually you at least upvote an answer that helps you(i.e. _use public properties_). That is the foundation of a free-open-high-quality knowledge base with so many contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [how to build custom actions in C# for MSI installers](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html).

This shows how to get a DLL that will run in a standard MSI, no matter if you build it with Wix, InstallShield or Advanced Installer. It also shows how to get/set properties.

Additional info:

- try to use [public properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370912(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SecurePropertiesList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371571(v=vs.85).aspx)
- **only** immediate custom actions can get/set a property